# Mysql Select String Function Problem

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select records in my table when it matches a row that ends with a particular value.

eg.

if 'oop' is found at the end of a particular record it select the record

Pls how can i go about it

thanks

Comment: the search string is not fixed, can be anything

Comment: i came up with this: select from table where substring('columnname', -(length('oop')))='oop'. will it do the same job? if it will which will u advise. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LIKE:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_column LIKE '%oop'
```

Note that this query will result in a full scan so it might be slow if you have many rows.

Comment: before i saw ur post, i came up with this: select from table where substring('columnname', -(length('oop')))='oop'. will it do the same job? if it will which will u advise. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from yourtable where somevalue like '%oop'
```

Comment: before i saw ur post, i came up with this: select from table where substring('columnname', -(length('oop')))='oop'. will it do the same job? if it will which will u advise. thanks

Comment: If you are OK with implementing your own solution in favor of a simple, concise answer suggested by several people in this thread, as well as taking the performance hit of multiple function calls, then yes, your answer is perfect.

Comment: thanks alex, actually what prompted my statement is this line: 'Note that this query will result in a full scan so it might be slow if you have many rows.' from Mark Byers. What am looking at is the performance. Hope u will understand my point of view, thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_column REGEXP 'oop'
```

Regular Expression Queries can open up some pretty cool extra features that like can't touch.